# Access 2013 VBA needed for making a stage-time table

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, recordset

I have two tables:

1. tblTimelist which contains a time table field (Time, short time) (from 00:00 til 23:45, with intervals of 00:15)
2. tblProgScheme which contains the fields prog_ID, BeginShow (short time), EndShow (short time) and ActName.

I want a list based on the BeginShow and EndShow times looking like this:

- 12:00 Justin Bieber
- 12:15 Justin Bieber
- 12:30 Justin Bieber
- 12:45 Justin Bieber
- 13:00 Miley Cyrus
- 13:15 Miley Cyrus
- 13:30 Miley Cyrus

In this example the values of the fields "BeginShow" and "EndShow" were 12:00 and 13:00 for Bieber respectively and 13:00 and 13:45 for Miley.
I tried all kinds of joins in queries without success.
I think I might solve the problem with VBA because I think I have to code something with a "Do Until Loop" but I cannot find the proper code to put the ActName value somewhere into tblTimeList and making the right criteria at the same time. 
Can somebody give me a hint where to find a clue?

Comment: If this is not a homework assignment forcing you to use VBA, you should be able to do this in a normal access query.  Join them on a range of time >= BeginShow AND time < EndShow.

Comment: Thanks Abra, for your quick reply. But if I join the tables as you suggest, I only see the occupied timeblocks. In order to compare stages with their acts I also must see the "empty"  time blocks. BTW it's not a homework assignment. It's just a hobby of mine and trying to help a festival organization.

Comment: That's great you are helping people who are into music. :) To see the "empty" time blocks, you need to do a "Left Join" on the tables.  Null values will show up where there are "empty" spaces (or no matching records).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... you found a place where the MS Access Query "Design View" throws hiccups.  It can not display queries that use > or < signs.

But even though "Design View" won't display the query nicely, you can go into "SQL View" and paste the following Left Join on a range query:

```
SELECT 
   tblTimeList.Time
   ,tblProgScheme.ActName
FROM 
   tblTimeList 
   LEFT JOIN tblProgScheme ON 
      tblTimeList.Time >= tblProgScheme.BeginShow 
      AND tblTimeList.Time < tblProgScheme.EndShow
ORDER BY tblTimeList.Time;
```

This should give you the results you are looking for. Save it and close the query while still in "SQL View".

The only danger is that if you open this in "Design View" and make changes, and then save it... it'll eliminate the code that has > or < signs.

**So don't do that.**

If you need changes, just make them in "SQL View".  (It'll do you good to learn how to code in straight SQL without the "Design View". You can make much more powerful and much more useful Queries that way.)

Also, keep in mind.  The above code **will** allow you to overlap concert times.  It will create a entry for each act at each valid time slot.  So you could have multiple records with the same time segment where an overlap occurs.  To identify if you have any, you can create another query that looks for the duplicate times.

Anyway, I hope that helps and I hope you get to enjoy lots of good music. :)

**EDIT**

Ok, I know Access 2013 will allow you to use Left Joins.  So maybe it's a syntax thing.  Double check all of your spellings of your tables and fields.  Also check capitalizations (although that shouldn't be a problem, access can be screwy sometimes).  Plus add parenthesis and make sure they match properly.  Access tries to add parenthesis if you don't include them.  Usually it gets it right, but sometimes it guesses wrong and mucks up your code.

With that in mind, try the following:

```
SELECT tblTimelist.Time, tblProgScheme.ActName FROM tblTimelist LEFT JOIN tblProgScheme ON ((tblTimelist.Time >= tblProgScheme.BeginShow) AND (tblTimelist.Time < tblProgScheme.EndShow)) ORDER BY tblTimelist.Time;
```

Comment: Thank you Abra. But the code above gave a error message "Join-expression not supported" while saving in SQL view. I use Access 2013 btw

Comment: I modified the code a bit and it works for me.  Double check spellings and field names. Hopefully this is just an Access wizard problem.

Comment: Abra, you're a genius! Thanks! Now I was able to make extra criteria for choosing the stage. Not by adding a simple WHERE clause in your code because that didn't work, but by making a subquery. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, subqueries are nice.  "SQL View" can open a whole new world of coding.  Lots of fun to get beyond the constraint's of "Design View".  Glad to be of help. :)